# Algorithm for conducting Westfall & Young permutation test under Multiple Hypothesis Testing given a list of raw(unadjusted) p values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, p-value, permutation-test, combining-p-values

I am currently trying to set up a python program to implement Westfall & Young (1993)'s minP permutation procedure using Python. The computationally efficient algorithm I was able to find by referring box 04 of Ge et al. (2003) https://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/633.pdf is given below.

[image]

Please note that I have rephrased the given algorithm, and would like to know if my implementation is correct. Any feedback on further improving my writing will be appreciated, and if there is any possibility of providing a python code to implement the method, it will be great.

The code I have created so far is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def minP_permutation_test(p_values, num_permutations=10000):
    # Sort p-values in ascending order
    sorted_p_values = np.sort(p_values)

    # Initialize an array to store adjusted p-values
    adjusted_p_values = np.zeros(len(sorted_p_values))

    # Permutation procedure
    for i, p_val in enumerate(sorted_p_values):
        # Simulate num_permutations random permutations
        permuted_stats = []
        for _ in range(num_permutations):
            # Shuffle the group labels (assuming two groups)
            shuffled_labels = np.random.permutation([0] * len(p_values))
            permuted_data = np.array(p_values)[shuffled_labels == 0]

            # Compute the permutation test statistic (e.g., mean difference)
            permuted_stat = np.abs(np.mean(permuted_data) - np.mean(p_values))
            permuted_stats.append(permuted_stat)

         # Calculate the adjusted p-value
        adjusted_p_values[i] = np.mean(permuted_stats <= np.abs(np.mean(p_values) - np.mean(permuted_data)))

     # Enforce monotonicity
     for j in range(len(adjusted_p_values) - 1):
        adjusted_p_values[j] = max(adjusted_p_values[j], adjusted_p_values[j + 1])

     return adjusted_p_values
```

## Example:

```
input_p_values = [0.001, 0.012, 0.038, 0.14, 0.25, 0.31, 0.55, 0.99]  
adjusted_p_vals = minP_permutation_test(input_p_values)

print("Adjusted p-values:", adjusted_p_vals)
```

The results I get here are wrong as each p-values is marked as 1.0, and I can't figure out why is occurs. If anyone can share a better working code, it will be of great help! TIA